# How to get the body element form the jQuery.load() response?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

HTML:

```
 <html> 
     <head>
         <title></title> 
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class="mainContainer"> dgdhgdhgd 
             <div class="header"></div>
             <div class="navigation"></div>
             <div class="content"></div>
             <div class="footer"></div>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

jQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

         $(function() {
             alert("hsahdjkha");
             $('#form1').append('<span id="result" ></span>');

             $('#result').load('sageframetemplating/layout.html', function() {
                 alert('Load was performed.');
                 $('#result').find('body').html();
                 alert($('#result').html());
                 test();
             });

         });

         function test() {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Default.aspx/Result",
                 data: "{ result:'" + $('#result').html() + "'}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(response) {
                     alert("Wa hooooooooo");
                 },
                 error: function() {
                     alert("error");
                 }
             });
         }

     </script>
```

I want to catch only body part of the `HTML` but I get:

```
<title></title> 
<div class="mainContainer"> dgdhgdhgd 
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="navigation"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

How it possible to catch only body part?

Comment: Nothing in your code even has an id of result or form1

Comment: @keith nop just i got above html page and try to retrive only body part

Comment: Why not supply a html section instead full html structure, in `sageframetemplating/layout.html`

Comment: @toopay because its a dynamic loaded html page.

Comment: Did you mean [webmethod] tag instead of [webmethods]? Even though you don't even show the backend handler though, so it might not be even relevant here. Removing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to insert a block of HTML containing a `<body>` and a `<head>` tag into the page.

Since you can't have multiple `<body>` tags within the page, they get stripped out, leaving you with the output you see.

One possible solution is to use [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead -- which doesn't dump the data straight into the page -- and parse the data before putting it into the page.

```
$.get('sageframetemplating/layout.html', function(data) {
    var parsedData = $(data).find("body").html();
    $("#result").html(parsedData);
});
```

I'll admit I wrote this without any testing on my end, so you may have to clean up the syntax yourself.

**EDIT**

From [`html()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

> This method is not available on XML documents.

Terrific.

The `data` object is really a `Document` object, which has a method [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp) which allows us to hack around with it and get our hands on a `NodeList`. If we then access the first item in the list, we get a [`Node`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247):

```
var node = data.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
```

At this point we can extract the results:

```
$("#result").append($(node).children())
```

This dirty, dirty hack will get you what you want for this very specific scenario.

Note can do horrible things if your page contains scripts.

Comment: im getting parseddata null but data is coming ..i thnk $(data) is not working ....any other ideas??

Comment: @Shree Well, we can try to debug it, sure. Check you have the correct casing and spelling for variables: e.g. parsedData: 2 d, one captial. Put in an `alert(data);` in there: do you get a document object?

Comment: @Henary not only document obj i got whole html . alert(data); works fine  but problem is data is not object thats why $(data).find("body").html();
giving null ..

Comment: Yes, the data is not an object, which is why it's passed through the jQuery constructor.

Comment: any other soln in your mind plz suggest i lost my whole day for this problem